# How to handle multiple files in a post petition to recover them and show them in a view?

Tags: html, django

I am trying to upload multiple image files with a form in html in django, but when trigger the button only one file is uploaded, how can I recover several files and show them in my view?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Búsqueda general</h4>
        <input type="file" name="document" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"> <br>
        <center><button type="submit" id="subir">Subir imagenes</button></center><br>
 </form>
 <ul>
        {% if uploaded_file_url %}
             <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
            <li><img src="{{ uploaded_file_url }}" title ="{{ filename }}" id="dragElement"></li>
        {% endif %}
</ul>
```

views.py

```
def cuad(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('document', False):
        myfile = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        print(request.FILES)
        return render(request, "visores/cuadrantes.html", {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,
            'filename': filename
        })
    return render(request, "visores/cuadrantes.html")
```

I get this on console when I print request:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'document': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140037.JPG 
(image/jpeg)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140038.JPG (image/jpeg)>, 
<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140039.JPG (image/jpeg)>, 
<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140043.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Comment: What are you asking? That shows that you have four separate files.

Comment: How can I recover this files:<MultiValueDict: {'document': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140037.JPG 
(image/jpeg)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140038.JPG (image/jpeg)>, 
<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140039.JPG (image/jpeg)>, 
<TemporaryUploadedFile: P5140043.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>  to show them in my template "visores/cuadrantes.html"

Comment: With `.getlist`, which you use in the if condition but not later.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuadrantes.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Búsqueda general</h4>
        <input type="file" name="document" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"> <br>
        <center><button type="submit" id="subir">Subir imagenes</button></center><br>
</form>
{% for filename, uploaded_file_url in uploaded_documents.items %}
    <li><img src="{{ uploaded_file_url }}" title ="{{ filename }}" id="dragElement"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def cuad(request):
    uploaded_documents = {}
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('document', False):
        myfiles = request.FILES.getlist('document')
        for document in myfiles:
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(document.name, document)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            uploaded_documents[filename] = uploaded_file_url
    return render(request, "visores/cuadrantes.html", {
        'uploaded_documents': uploaded_documents,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
def cuad(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('document', False):
        myfiles = request.FILES['document']
        uploaded_documents = {}
        for document in myfiles:
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(document.name, document)
            uploaded_file_url = (fs.url(filename))
            uploaded_documents[filename] = uploaded_file_url

        return render(request, "visores/cuadrantes.html", {
            'uploaded_documents': uploaded_documents,
        })
    return render(request, "visores/cuadrantes.html")
```

in the template:

```
{% for document in uploaded_documents %}
    {% for filename, file_url in document.items %}
         <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ file_url }}">{{ file_url }}</a></p>
        <li><img src="{{ file_url }}" title ="{{ filename }}" id="dragElement"></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I inserted a print  to check why isn't finishing the "for document in myfiles"  and I saw in console that is uploading several files with different codes at the end, something like this:    /media/P5140038.JPG
/media/P5140038_VHq0gUi.JPG
/media/P5140038_buCrNzz.JPG
/media/P5140038_oEFxWkY.JPG
/media/P5140038_4qQFjWe.JPG
/media/P5140038_15wGcvU.JPG
etc,

Comment: Django automatically generate a diffrent filename if a file with the same name already exist.

Comment: There is an AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'name', it refers to line: filename = fs.save(document.name, document)

Comment: try to create a value `i=0` before the for then replace the line with : `filename = fs.save(str(i), document)` and before the end of the for do `i +=1`. If it works, that mean you have to create a use a function to generate a file name for your files

Comment: I replaced line `myfile = request.FILES['document']` with `myfile = request.FILES.getlist('document')` and it worked fine. Now when I see carpet **/media** files are there, the only problem now is that my template doesn't load any image inside `<ul></ul>`

Comment: everything works fine, but for any reason I can't receive files in my template, it's like uploaded_documents were empty, can you help me please.

Comment: when you try to print uploaded_documents what do you see (in view before the return)

Comment: I just uploaded 2 files and printing them in template with html inside <p></p>(and also in view) it shows this: `{'P5140039.JPG': '/media/P5140039.JPG', 'P5140040.JPG': '/media/P5140040.JPG'}`

Comment: can you update you post with all the code you currently have it will be easier to debug the issue. thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ben, I just solved it, I posted my solution based in your answer.